# how to exclude folder from build next js but still read from it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, next.js, build

I have a folder of a lot of json files. I want to exclude it from getting into build as it would increase the build size. But I also need to get data from those files and can't store in database. Is there any way to achieve this?

I have tried exclude folder at next.config.js but couldn't find any changes

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to exclude the folder in `next.config.js`, lets say all the data that you need to exlude is in the `data` folder:

```
const nextConfig = {
  // ...
  exclude: ['data'],
};
```

Second you need to import the `data` folder using `require` in order the use the json data:

```
const users = require('./data/users.json');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I know in which file do I need import data exactly? Do you mean at /pages/api in next js project?

And also am facing this warning while build

warn  - Invalid next.config.js options detected: 
  - The root value has an unexpected property, exclude, which is not in the list of allowed properties

Comment: create data folder in the root directory, and add you json files to it, then use them in your components

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding the directory I wanted ignored to the `exclude` key in `tsconfig.json` (only applicable if using TypeScript)

```
{
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "MY_FOLDER"]
}
```